# Use write() to write char* to file from user input

Tags: c, system-calls

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a path from stdin and saves that path to a file.
Despite many attempts, I have lost any kind of sense of how to properly do it. Can someone show me how to do it right?
This is my code:

```
void char_to_file(const char *pathname, const char *dest)
{
        int fd_1;
        if (fd_1 = open(dest, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666) == -1)
                custom_error_shout("OPEN FD_1");
        while (*(pathname) != '\0')
        {
                *(pathname++);
                if (write(fd_1, &pathname, 1) == -1)
                        custom_error_shout("WRITE TO FILE");
        }

        if (close(fd_1) == -1)
                custom_error_shout("CLOSE FD_1");
}
```

The file will be created but nothing will be written in it. No errors have come out of this.

Comment: Why low-level writes instead of `fwrite` and friends on `FILE*`?

Comment: What is `*(pathname++)` supposed to do? Wouldn't `pathname++` be sufficient? I'm not even sure why you'd be manipulating that pointer at all, though.

Comment: What does "saves that path to a file" mean? Are you saying "copy contents of file at given path" or "copies the literal path name to the output file"? If you're dumping `pathname` to a file, why are you writing byte by byte instead of just `write(fd_1, pathname, strlen(pathname))`?

Comment: At least, don't use &pathname, that'll write one byte of the value of the pointer. How long is the file after this runs? Also, you increment pathname before you write, so you'll lose the first character, then write the zero byte at the end. The error check should be != 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason nothing is written is you reset `fd_1` to the result of the conditional `open(..) == -1`, which unless open fails means the result will be `0` (`STDIN_FILENO`). If the `open()` does fail and returns `-1`, then `fd_1` will equal `1` (`STDOUT_FILENO`). So you are trying to `write` to `stdin` unless `open()` fails.

This is due to your failure to wrap your assignment in parentheses, e.g. `if (fd_1 = open() == -1)` -- which should be `if ((fd_1 = open()) == -1)`. Otherwise `==` (relational operator) has higher [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `=` (simple assignment) and the result of `open(..) == -1` is assigned to `fd_1`.

To correct the problem, you need:

```
if ((fd_1 = open(dest, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666)) == -1)
```

(**note:** your choice of `mode` of `0666` will be subject to the system `umask` and will likely results in actual permissions of `0644`. See [man 2 umask](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html))

Your `write` command should pass the address of the first character, not a pointer to that address, e.g.

```
    if (write(fd_1, pathname, 1) == -1)
```

You should enable compiler warnings. E.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc/clang or `/W3` for VS (for other compilers, check the options). With warnings enable, you should receive the warning about a *computed value not used* with:

```
    *(pathname++);
```

To advance the pointer, simply use `pathname++;`. Dereferencing the result has no purpose if it is not being assigned or otherwise being used.

If you have no other issues with the strings in `pathname` or `dest`, and your error macros work properly -- then this should fix your problem. (with the note, using `fopen` and file-stream operations like `fputs()` makes much more sense).

Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

You sure chose the hard way to do this. Like @tadman suggested in comments, try this instead:

```
void char_to_file(const char *pathname, const char *dest)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(dest, "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        custom_error_shout("Something went wrong opening the file");
        return;
    }

    if (fputs(pathname, fp) == EOF)
        custom_error_shout("Something went wrong writing to the file");

    fclose(fp);
}
```